# Run a Vim command from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, vim

This is related to a question I asked earlier but I would like to keep it separate in case anyone else can find use in it.

I have a command that I am running on a file called dummy.out from the command line which is as followed

```
vim -E -s dummy.out <<-EOF
   :%s/old/new/g
   :%s/old2/new2/g
   :%s/old3/new3/g
   :update
   :quit
EOF
```

from the command line this is working but when I add it to my bash file bashscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# bash script

var01="start script"
echo $var01

vim -E -s dummy.out <<-EOF
   :%s/old/new/g
   :%s/old2/new2/g
   :%s/old3/new3/g
   :update
   :quit
EOF
```

I get the following error

```
warning: here-document at line 7 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'EOF')
```

How would I get this command line command to run inside this bash file?

Comment: looks like typical line ending confusion. Did you edit it with a Windows editor?

Comment: so this script works just fine for me: bash script.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it looks like the EOF was just a lot more sensitive than I excpected

this doesn't work

```
vim -E -s dummy.out <<-EOF
   :%s/old/new/g
   :%s/old2/new2/g
   :%s/old3/new3/g
   :update
   :quit
EOF
```

this does

```
vim -E -s dummy.out << EOF
:%s/old/new/g
:%s/old2/new2/g
:%s/old3/new3/g
:update
:quit
EOF
```

Comment: is your editor translating tabs to spacres? <<- only works on actual tabs

Comment: It is yes but for this script I decided to leave out tabs all together